# Kafka ProducerListener does not work with multiple spring cloud stream binders

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

If I specify custom/multiple spring spring cloud stream binders, along with a ProducerListener bean, the ProducerListener callbacks do not work.

```
spring.cloud.stream.default-binder=secondaryKafka

spring.cloud.stream.binders.secondaryKafka.type=kafka

spring.cloud.stream.binders.secondaryKafka.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
```

But when I use the default binder (kafka) without any custom binders, the ProducerListener works.

I can also see that when the KafkaTemplate Bean gets created by KafkaAutoConfiguration, the correct ProducerListener bean gets set.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: This might be a bug that we should look into. Can you create an issue in Spring Cloud Stream with these details or a small sample application we can test against?

Comment: @sobychacko I just submitted this issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2665